# In theory how much bigger would the universe be if Inflation had lasted longer?

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, universe

In theory, Inflation started at $10^{-36}$ seconds after the Big Bang and ended at $10^{-32}$ seconds.
But let's imagine Inflation had lasted one second instead.
In theory how much bigger would that make the known universe?

Comment: If the universe is a closed structure, it would go on much further behind the horizon then nowadays. It's the question though if matter could evolve into galaxies, if the number of particles torn from the vacuum would be the same. It would be a quasi empty universe.

Comment: @shaihorowitz not true, the size of the observable universe is 93 billion light-years

Answer (score 1):

The length of the inflationary epoch isn't known. When people say that inflation ended $10^{-32}\text{ s}$ "after the big bang", they really mean that the $e$-folding time (the time for the scale factor to increase linearly by a factor of $e$) is roughly that. Inflation has to last for at least 50-60 $e$-folds, so it actually has to last much longer than the time "after the big bang" at which it ends. See [this answer](/a/505603) for more details, including an explanation of where this funny convention comes from.

If the $e$-fold time is $10^{-32}\text{ s}$, then for each additional second that inflation lasts, the volume of the universe increases by another factor of

$$\left( e^{10^{32}} \right)^3 \approx 10^{100000000000000000000000000000000}.$$

That seems ridiculous, but many things about the world we live in seem ridiculous, so who knows.

Comment: well, it seems ridiculous only because we are comparing it to today's characteristic timescales that we are used to. One second is incredibly long for very early universe